# AngularJs inline edit in a modal

Tags: angularjs, forms, x-editable

I'm following this tutorial http://plnkr.co/edit/BjWwXIlYyyLvRnVwO8m8?p=preview in a simple table and it's working well but when I use xeditable in a modal it don't work.
this is an example of my code:

```
 <div class="modal-body">
   <form name="langForm" class="form-horizontal" editable-form>
     <table st-table="displayedCollection" st-safe-src="lang.LangList" class="table table-striped" ng-hide="myVar">
       <tbody>
         <tr>
           <td class="text-center"> 
             <input type="text" required="" ng-model="lang.vLang" class="form-control" placeholder="Language" > 
           </td>
         </tr>
       </tbody>
    </table>
 <table st-table="langs" st-safe-src="LangList" class="table table-striped" >
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="text-center"><small>Language</small></th>
                <th class="text-center"><small>Actions</small></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="lang in langs track by $index">
                <td class="text-center">
<a href="#" editable-text="user.name" onaftersave="updatePerson(lang)">{{lang.vLang}}</a>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center">            
                    <div class="btn-group btn-group-xs">
            <i class="hi hi-remove"></i>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
                </form>
            </div>
```

Any help please

Comment: Hi, you should add more information, I could go and read that tutorial but I'm not really into it. If you describe your problem with more info I can try to help you. For example, "It didn't work" its not enough, what didn't work? Did it work outside a modal? Why do you need xeditable with angular?
Basically I want to know whats the objective of what you are doing, what you have tried and what is really wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your replay the problem was with the form, xeditable don't work in a form.